Made a function named mostrar tablas, but its not showing the wins and losses
EDIT: Managed to solve it. if anyone needs a program to add information to a table of any kind, i recommend to keep it simple. i simply rewrote both functions, made two variables in the struct which represent wins and losses and initialize them (very important) to store the wins and losses, and simply passed the list of teams where the wins and losses where stored onto mostrar tablas. so basically simulate game gives me a winner based on who has more points, and said winner is stored on the two variables in the struct, where is later used in mostrar tablas to show wins and loses, so i simply passed down the list where the struct is onto mostrar tablas as the only argument.
Please ignore the printfs i just wanted to add extra personality to the program. So i created these 3 functions (They are in spanish, but the logic should be there, sorry in advance), and i wanted to store the amount of wins and losses each team had after simulating a game in the function simular juego, after some testing i found out that resultados was being sent as null to mostrar tablas, because of this the rest of the function cannot work. but after trying different methods to assign value to resultados, tablas still either displays nothing or it gives me the message "They are no teams to show" present in the beginnig of the mostrar tablas fucntion that i put to ensure that the values passed cannot be null. here is the code:
void simular_juego_y_mostrar_maximos(JUGADOR *jugadores, ESTADISTICA *estadisticas, int num_jugadores, const JUGADOR *lista_jugadores, const EQUIPO *lista_equipos, ESTJUEGO *resultados) {
    printf("Simulacion de juego de baloncesto:\n");
    printf("\nAnnouncer: Holaaaaaaaa a todos, ninos y ninas, damas y caballeros!!!!!\n");
    printf("\nEs tiempoooooooooooo de un juegooooooooooo de basketball!!!!!!!!!!!!\n");
    printf("\nLos dos equipos de esta noche parecen tener plantillas muy parecidas\n");
    printf("\nBuenaaaaaaaaa suerte y que gane el mejor!!!!!!!\n");
    const JUGADOR *temp = lista_jugadores;

    // Mostrar encabezados de la tabla
    printf("+---------+----------------------+----------------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+\n");
    printf("| Código  |        Nombre        |       Apellido       |    Puntos     |  Asistencias  |   Rebotes     |    Total      |\n");
    printf("+---------+----------------------+----------------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+\n");

    // Calcular y mostrar los puntos totales de cada equipo
    int puntos_equipo1 = 0;
    int puntos_equipo2 = 0;

    // Iterar sobre cada jugador y generar estadísticas aleatorias
    for (int i = 0; i < num_jugadores && temp != NULL; i++) {
        // Determinar el equipo del jugador actual
        const EQUIPO *equipo_jugador = NULL;
        for (const EQUIPO *equipo = lista_equipos; equipo != NULL; equipo = equipo->siguiente) {
            if (strcmp(temp->codequipo, equipo->codequipo) == 0) {
                equipo_jugador = equipo;
                break;
            }
        }

        // Mostrar encabezado del equipo si es el primer jugador del equipo
        if (equipo_jugador == lista_equipos) {
            printf("+-------------------------------------------------- %s --------------------------------------------------+\n", equipo_jugador->nombre);
        } else if (equipo_jugador == lista_equipos->siguiente) {
            printf("+-------------------------------------------------- %s --------------------------------------------------+\n", equipo_jugador->nombre);
        }

        // Generar puntos aleatorios en el rango de 0 a 30
        int puntos = rand() % 31;
        // Generar asistencias aleatorias en el rango de 0 a puntos
        int asistencias = rand() % (puntos + 1);
        // Generar rebotes aleatorios en el rango de 0 a 20
        int rebotes = rand() % 21;

        // Actualizar las estadísticas del jugador
        estadisticas[i].puntos = puntos;
        estadisticas[i].asistencias = asistencias;
        estadisticas[i].rebotes = rebotes;

        // Sumar los puntos del jugador al equipo correspondiente
        if (strcmp(temp->codequipo, lista_equipos->codequipo) == 0) {
            puntos_equipo1 += puntos;
        } else if (strcmp(temp->codequipo, lista_equipos->siguiente->codequipo) == 0) {
            puntos_equipo2 += puntos;
        }

        // Mostrar estadísticas del jugador en la tabla
        printf("| %-7s | %-20s | %-20s | %-13d | %-13d | %-13d | %-13d |\n",
               temp->codjugador, temp->nombres, temp->apellidos, puntos, asistencias, rebotes, puntos + asistencias + rebotes);

        temp = temp->siguiente;
    }

    // Mostrar líneas finales de la tabla
    printf("+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+\n");

    // Mostrar los puntos totales de cada equipo
    printf("|                        %s: %-12d          |                        %s: %-12d          |\n", lista_equipos->nombre, puntos_equipo1, lista_equipos->siguiente->nombre, puntos_equipo2);
    printf("+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+\n");

    // Mostrar los máximos y el triple doble
    int max_puntos = 0, max_asistencias = 0, max_rebotes = 0;
    char jugador_max_puntos[MAX_NOMBRE_JUGADOR], jugador_max_asistencias[MAX_NOMBRE_JUGADOR], jugador_max_rebotes[MAX_NOMBRE_JUGADOR];
    char triple_doble_equipo1[MAX_NOMBRE_JUGADOR], triple_doble_equipo2[MAX_NOMBRE_JUGADOR];
    triple_doble_equipo1[0] = '\0'; // Inicializar la cadena triple_doble_equipo1
    triple_doble_equipo2[0] = '\0'; // Inicializar la cadena triple_doble_equipo2

    temp = lista_jugadores; // Restablecer el puntero temporal
    printf("Que gran juego acabamos de verrrrrrr!!!!!\n");
    printf("\nEscuchen este estadio!!!!! WOOOOOOOOOO WOOOOOOOOOO!!!!!!\n");
    printf("\nYa con este juego concluido pasemos a las estadisticas\n");
    printf("\nTraidas por ti gracias a geico, save 15 porcent or more on car insurance\n");
    printf("\nAnd arbys, arbys we got the meats!!!!!!!\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < num_jugadores && temp != NULL; i++) {
        if (estadisticas[i].puntos > max_puntos) {
            max_puntos = estadisticas[i].puntos;
            strcpy(jugador_max_puntos, temp->nombres);
        }
        if (estadisticas[i].asistencias > max_asistencias) {
            max_asistencias = estadisticas[i].asistencias;
            strcpy(jugador_max_asistencias, temp->nombres);
        }
        if (estadisticas[i].rebotes > max_rebotes) {
            max_rebotes = estadisticas[i].rebotes;
            strcpy(jugador_max_rebotes, temp->nombres);
        }
        // Verificar si un jugador hizo un triple doble para cada equipo
        if (estadisticas[i].puntos > 10 && estadisticas[i].asistencias > 10 && estadisticas[i].rebotes > 10) {
            if (strcmp(temp->codequipo, lista_equipos->codequipo) == 0) {
                printf("\nLos jugadores que lograron un triple doble\n");
                printf("\nGran juego de %s del equipo %s logro conseguir un mitico triple doble!!!\n", temp->nombres, lista_equipos->nombre);
            } else if (strcmp(temp->codequipo, lista_equipos->siguiente->codequipo) == 0) {
                printf("\nLos jugadores que lograron un triple doble son:\n");
                printf("\nFantastico juego de %s del equipo %s obtuvo su triple dobleeee!!!!\n", temp->nombres, lista_equipos->siguiente->nombre);
            }
        }

        temp = temp->siguiente;
    }
       // Determinar el ganador y el perdedor
    if (puntos_equipo1 > puntos_equipo2) {
        printf("\nEl equipo %s ha ganado el juego con un total de %d puntos.\n", lista_equipos->nombre, puntos_equipo1);
        printf("\nEl equipo %s ha perdido el juego con un total de %d puntos.\n", lista_equipos->siguiente->nombre, puntos_equipo2);
    } else if (puntos_equipo1 < puntos_equipo2) {
        printf("\nEl equipo %s ha ganado el juego con un total de %d puntos.\n", lista_equipos->siguiente->nombre, puntos_equipo2);
        printf("\nEl equipo %s ha perdido el juego con un total de %d puntos.\n", lista_equipos->nombre, puntos_equipo1);
    } else {
        printf("\nEl juego ha terminado en un empate con un total de %d puntos para ambos equipos.\n", puntos_equipo1);
    }
    // Mostrar los máximos
    printf("\nSiempre se ha dicho que el jugador mas valioso es el que anota mucho!!!!\n");
    printf("\nIncreible juego de %s logro liderar las tablas de puntos de ambos equipos con %d puntos\n", jugador_max_puntos, max_puntos);
    printf("\nAsistencias, en vez de anotar ayudas a tus miembros de equipos a anotar, *se limpia lagrimas* que hermosa estadistica\n");
    printf("\nEl jugador que realizo la mayor cantidad de asistencias es %s con %d asistencias, liderando ambos equipos!!!\n", jugador_max_asistencias, max_asistencias);
    printf("\nProbablemente la esatdistica mas infravalorada del juego, pero no la menos importante\n");
    printf("\nUn aplauso a aquellos jugadores que se quedan bajo aro y pelean por sus rebotes, te queremos!!!!!!!!!!!!!\n");
    printf("\nEres un grande %s por obtener la mayor cantidad de rebotes con %d, definitivamente hiciste el juego mas interesante\n", jugador_max_rebotes, max_rebotes);
    printf("\nGraciasssss a todos por venir a este gran juego!!!!!!!!!!!!!\n");
    printf("\npublico: Heyyyyyyyyy anunciador dame tu autografooooooooo!!!\n");
    printf("\nLos siento querido publico pero este hombre es de una sola mujerrrrrrr y un hombreeee\n");
    printf("\nQuedense con nosotros despues del juego, un concierto de Luis Miguellllllllll\n");
    printf("\npublico: woooooooooo luis miguel te amamosssssssss!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!\n");
    printf("\nOjala cante noche de carnaval\n");
    printf("\nPero antes veamos la tabla de posiciones");
    // Generar un código de juego aleatorio de 5 dígitos
    char codigo_juego[6]; // Un espacio adicional para el carácter nulo '\0'
    generar_codigo_juego(codigo_juego);
    // Determinar el ganador y el perdedor del juego
    char ganador[MAX_NOMBRE_EQUIPO];
    char perdedor[MAX_NOMBRE_EQUIPO];
    if (puntos_equipo1 > puntos_equipo2) {
        strcpy(ganador, lista_equipos->codequipo);
        strcpy(perdedor, lista_equipos->siguiente->codequipo);
    } else if (puntos_equipo1 < puntos_equipo2) {
        strcpy(ganador, lista_equipos->siguiente->codequipo);
        strcpy(perdedor, lista_equipos->codequipo);
    } else {
        // Empate, ambos equipos son considerados ganadores
        strcpy(ganador, lista_equipos->codequipo);
        strcpy(perdedor, lista_equipos->siguiente->codequipo);
    }

    // Almacenar los resultados del juego
    strcpy(resultados->ganador, ganador);
    strcpy(resultados->perdedor, perdedor);

    // Llamar a la función mostrar_tabla y pasar los resultados del juego
    mostrar_tabla(lista_equipos, resultados, codigo_juego);

    // Llamar a la función mostrar_tabla y pasarle el código de juego generado
  //mostrar_tabla(lista_equipos, *resultados, codigo_juego);
}

void generar_codigo_juego(char codigo_juego[LENCOD]) {
    // Semilla para la función de generación de números aleatorios
    srand(time(NULL));

    // Generar un código de juego aleatorio de 5 dígitos
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        codigo_juego[i] = '0' + rand() % 10; // Números aleatorios del 0 al 9
    }
    codigo_juego[5] = '\0'; // Agregar el carácter nulo al final
}


void mostrar_tabla(const EQUIPO *lista_equipos, const ESTJUEGO *resultados, const char codigo_juego[LENCOD]) {
    if (lista_equipos == NULL || resultados == NULL) {
        printf("\nNo hay equipos o resultados para mostrar.\n");
        return;
    }

    printf("Tabla de victorias y derrotas:\n");
    printf("------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("| Código del Equipo | Victorias | Derrotas |\n");
    printf("------------------------------------------\n");

    const EQUIPO *temp_equipo = lista_equipos;

    while (temp_equipo != NULL) {
        int victorias = 0;
        int derrotas = 0;
        const ESTJUEGO *temp_resultado = resultados;

        while (temp_resultado != NULL) {
            // Verificar si el equipo está involucrado en el juego con el código proporcionado
            if (strcmp(temp_resultado->codjuego, codigo_juego) == 0) {
                if (strcmp(temp_resultado->ganador, temp_equipo->codequipo) == 0) {
                    victorias++;
                } else if (strcmp(temp_resultado->perdedor, temp_equipo->codequipo) == 0) {
                    derrotas++;
                }
            }
            temp_resultado = temp_resultado->siguiente;
        }

        printf("| %-17s | %-9d | %-9d |\n", temp_equipo->codequipo, victorias, derrotas);
        temp_equipo = temp_equipo->siguiente;
    }

    printf("------------------------------------------\n");
}

here are is the main struct that im passing
typedef struct EstJuego {
    char codjuego[LENCOD];
    char codestadistica[LENCOD];
    char codjugador[LENCOD];
    ESTADISTICA *estadistica;
    char ganador[MAX_NOMBRE_EQUIPO];
    char perdedor[MAX_NOMBRE_EQUIPO];
    int cantidad;
    int puntos;
    int asistencias;
    int rebotes;
    struct EstJuego *siguiente;
    struct EstJuego *anterior;
} ESTJUEGO;

here is the main function
int main() {
    CIUDAD *lista_ciudades = NULL;
    EQUIPO *lista_equipos = NULL;
    JUGADOR *lista_jugadores = NULL;
    JUEGO *lista_juegos = NULL;
    ESTJUEGO *estadisticas = NULL;
    EQUIPO *nuevo_equipo = NULL;
    JUEGO *nuevo_juego = NULL;
    ESTADISTICA *lista_estadisticas = NULL;
    srand(time(NULL));
    ESTJUEGO *resultados = NULL;

I expected mostrar tablas to show after the simulation a table of data the puts the winner and the loser, ex. Team 1 wins: 1 losses:0, team 2 wins:0 losses:1. but resultados is not being passed an when it is being passed it the table shows no such data. perhaps there is an alternative way to build the mostrar tablas function that makes the process easier. like i said the comments and code are in spanish, but the logic should be there, any help i could get would be great. Thanks in advance.

main() has ESTJUEGO *resultados = NULL;. None of the code you showed reassigns it.

This line should fail strcpy(resultados->ganador, ganador);

@Uziel Almonte – Post a whole program rather than scattered, incomplete pieces.

@Armali but keep in mind to remove irrelevant parts (like the whole cascade of printf(...) Ie create a minimal reproducible example
